# Integer factorization $n = pq$ with additional knowledge of $\lfloor \sqrt{p} \rfloor \oplus \lfloor \sqrt{q}\rfloor$

Tags: rsa, factoring

We know that we can factor integer $n = pq$ when we know that $p\oplus q$, where $\oplus$ means xor. If we know $\lfloor \sqrt{p} \rfloor \oplus \lfloor \sqrt{q}\rfloor$, can we factor $n$?

Comment: The question is unlikely to have any practical application to cryptography, but it's nevertheless fun. The answer might depend on $\log_2(n)$, and $-\log_2((p-q)/(p+q))$.

Comment: Do you have a link on how to factor if you have the XOR of the two factors?  That sounds like a cool trick.  Knowing $p + q$ also factors $pq$.

Comment: @Myria, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2087588/integer-factorization-with-additional-knowledge-of-p-oplus-q

Comment: @fgrieu, I guess we can find all possible $\lfloor\sqrt{p}\rfloor$ and $\lfloor\sqrt{q}\rfloor$ first, but I don't know what to do.